# Enable swipe in tabbed page on Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Swiping pages doesn't work when using a TabbedPage in Xamarin.Forms on Android.

Is there a way to enable it? Do I need to create a custom renderer?

Answer (score 1):

This type of behaviour is not common on all platforms so you will need to create a custom renderer.

The only gesture recogniser in Xamarin.Forms is [TapGestureRecognizer](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer/) but I think they are working on adding more. Here are some useful examples that will point you in the right direction for creating the custom renderer:

1. [RobGibbens](https://github.com/RobGibbens/XamarinFormsGestureRecognizers)
2. [MR.Gesture](https://github.com/MichaelRumpler/GestureSample)

Another option is [MR.Gestures](http://www.mrgestures.com/#Overview) which adds Down, Up, Tapping, Tapped, DoupleTapped, LongPressing, LongPressed, Panning, Panned, Swiped, Pinching, Pinched, Rotating and Rotated events to each and every layout.

Comment: All these links for gestures, but how would you go about creating a custom renderer for TabbedPage? I made many custom renderers for different views, but I don't understand how pages rendering work.

Answer (score 0):

You can now just apply the material design. It's explained [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: I mean the tabbed page of material design makes pages swiping. So, all you have to do is to apply material design and then create your tabbed page in xamarin forms as normal. You can see how to apply material design [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/)